# Chrome window name to persist on the window itself

Tags: google-chrome, windows-11

I am using chrome browser on Windows 11. After I name a chrome window I want to see its name on the chrome window's title bar?

I know I can see the names of the chrome windows using Alt + Tab or Windows + Tab, but I want the name to persist on their respective windows itself. Is it possible?

Comment: See the name where - the title bar ?

Comment: Yes, on the title bar

Comment: Try the extension [Tab Modifier](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-modifier/hcbgadmbdkiilgpifjgcakjehmafcjai). Or *Settings > More tools > Name window...*